# Set cell value based on value in other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a following table structure:

```
    --- c1 ------- c2 ---- c3 ------ c4
 r1: **0001**  **word1**
 r2:   0002      word2  **0001**  **word1**
 r3:   0003      word3    0002      word2
```

I would like to set column three values automatically, so that if there is some word in column 4, then program should check column 2 and try to find the same word. If found, then column 1 value should be used as a column 3 value.

I could do that manually, but it's more work and it gets problematic if I ever add new rows. Column 1 value is equal to row number, so it's updated automatically if new rows added. Now I would like to set my data so that also column 3 would be updated automatically in those cases.

What is the right formula to make that happen?

Comment: Have you tried an `If()` statement? Please show us any formulas you've attempted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
=IF(D1<>"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,B:B,0)),"")
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

For structured table references:

```
=IF([@Col4]<>"",INDEX([Col1],MATCH([@Col4],[Col2],0)),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I have a feeling that @m5seppal will have to translate to [structured table references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to make this work! My Excel doesn't accept those formulas with commas and wants semicolons instead but otherwise this works. Also, I had never heard about structured table references before, huge help for me! :)

Comment: Could you check if you could help me with my follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301224/how-to-use-if-statement-with-comma-separated-values

Answer (score 1):

If you slightly rearrange your worksheet, then the `VLOOKUP()` function can be used.  I swapped your `A` and `B` (first and second) columns to arrive at this:

```
  --- A ----  B  ---- C  ---  D
r1: word1    0001
r2: word2    0002    0001   word1
r3: word3    0003    0002   word2
```

Enter into `C1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1, A$1:B$3, 2, FALSE)
```

and copy this formula down the `C` column.

The reason for swapping the first two columns is that `VLOOKUP()` always looks in the first column for the match.